# split up this string?

Tags: java, string

i have an external text file which is:

```
-To Kill a Mockingbird by Harper Lee.
-The Great Gatsby by Scott Fitzgerald.
-Hamlet by William Shakespeare.
-Then Catch in the Rye by J.D Salinger.
-One Hundred Years of Solitude by Gabriel Garcia Marquez.
-The Hobbit by J.R.R Tolkien.
-Moby Dick by Herman Melville.
-A Tale of two Cities by Charles Dickens.
-Don Quixoteby Miguel de Cervantes.
-Love in the Time of Cholera by Gabriel Garcia Marquez.
-Of Mice and Men by John Steinbeck.
-Fahrenheit 451 by Ray Bradbury.
-Stranger in a Strange Land by Robert Heinlein.
-Siddartha by Herman Heese.
-Atlas Shrugged by Ayn Rand.
-The Count of Monte Cristo by Alexandre Dumas.
-The Iliad by Homer.
-The Odyssey by Homer.
-A Wrinkle in Time by Madeleine L'Engle.
-Inferno by Dante Alighieri.
-Paradise Lost by John Milton.
-Alice's Adventures in Wonderland by Lewis Carroll.
-War and Peace by Leo Tolstoy.
-Frankenstein by Mary Shelley.
-Romeo and Juliet by William Shakespeare.
-Exodus by Leon Uris.
-1984 by George Orwell.
```

what i am trying to do is to split up the strings for each line and store them on a arraylist
i just dont know why it jumps from the first line to the third line when reading this text file:
my code:

```
bookSearch = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("src/booksNames.txt")).useDelimiter(" by ");
            books = new ArrayList<Books>();
            String storeName = "";
            String storeAuthor = "";

            while(bookSearch.hasNextLine())
            {

                storeName = bookSearch.next().split("by")[0];
                storeAuthor = bookSearch.next().split("(by)|(\\.)")[0];

                bookSearch.nextLine();              

                info = new Books(storeName, storeAuthor);
                books.add(info);
            }
```

what I get is To Kill a Mocking Bird by Harper Lee and then it jumps to Hamlet by William Shakespeare! It just keeps ignoring the second, fourth, sixth line, etcc.....
any help would be appreciated!!

every title and author is a separate line!

Answer (score 3):

You have called bookSearch.next() two times inside loop.bookSearch.nextLine() skips to the next object every time.

```
while(bookSearch.hasNextLine())
            {

                storeName = bookSearch.next().split("by")[0]; 
                storeAuthor = bookSearch.next().split("(by)|(\\.)")[0]; // The error lies here, bookSearch.next() skips to the next object every time

                bookSearch.nextLine();              

                info = new Books(storeName, storeAuthor);
                books.add(info);
            }
```

Correct Implementation :

```
while(bookSearch.hasNextLine())
            {
                String bookString = bookSearch.nextLine();
                storeName = bookString.split("by")[0];
                storeAuthor = bookString.split("by")[1];

                info = new Books(storeName, storeAuthor);
                books.add(info);
            }
```

Comment: now, my storeAuthor stores the same information as storeName which is the title! it keeps going line by line but storeAuthor references to title not author! what could be going wrong?

Comment: Use the splitted string at index 1. author = bookString.split("by")[1]; However you may have to remove the trailing "."

Comment: thanks man! you've helped a lot! i haven't figured out what my error is yet!! i am out of ideas right now,, i bet it's just a stupid mistake!

Comment: You have called bookSearch.next() two times inside loop. Everytime you do a .next() on the object, it fetches the next line from the file. Hence you faced this error. In my solution, I am calling it just once.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you call `bookSearch.next()` twice in your `while` loop

Answer (score 1):

You have called `bookSearch.next()` two times inside loop and `bookSearch.nextLine()` one time.

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.

```
while(bookSearch.hasNextLine())
{
      String[] book = bookSearch.next();
      storeName = book.split("by")[0];
      storeAuthor = book.split("(by)|(\\.)")[1];
      info = new Books(storeName, storeAuthor);
      books.add(info);
}
```

Comment: bookSearch.next() will return a String and not Books object

Comment: @Quoi now, my storeAuthor stores the same information as storeName which is the title! it keeps going line by line but storeAuthor references to title not author! what could be going wrong?

Comment: @Quoi when i run the program the line: storeAuthor = book.split("(by)|(\\.)")[1]; produces a compiler error, and if i change [1] to [0], i get the same result as storeName!

Answer (score 0):

use something like this

```
try{
        FileReader fr=new FileReader("Test.txt");
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);

        while((str=br.readLine()) != null){
        strBuf.append(str);
                //here you can add the str to your arrayList

        }
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
```

here Test.txt is the your input file.This code snippet will will fetch line by line data

from the text file.

Hope this was what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to read file. Also you should take followings into account.

- You should first check if it contains "by" keyword because there is a line that doesn't contain "by" such as "Don Quixoteby Miguel de Cervantes.".
- You should split using the spaces between the " by " keyword because since "Gatsby" also contains "by" it will split this also and give you wrong result.

  ```
  public void readFile(String fileName) {
  DataInputStream in = null;
  try {
      in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(fileName)));
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

      String line;
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          if (line.contains(" by ")) {
              String[] arr = line.split(" by ");
              String book = arr[0];
              String author = arr[1];

              System.out.println("Book : " + book + " Author : " + author + "\n");
              System.out.println("\n");
          } else {
              System.out.println(line + "\n");
          }
      }
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
      if (in != null) {
          try {
              in.close();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: That reads the file but does nothing for splitting the lines.

Answer (score 0):

You're about 90% there.  One of the things to note is what [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) returns - it gives you back an array of `String`, which you do correctly note.  However, you would be much better served if you created the array for each line you were reading, and performed your processing that way.

Also, you're calling `next()` twice.  Recall what [`Scanner.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) actually does - you would be best served creating local variables to hold either the `String` or the split `String[]`.

Comment: i just dont know what's wrong with this code! i am debugging it with eclipse and i just dont get the desired results! i've tried everything! i bet it's stupid mistake!

Comment: Get some rest and re-read the answers here.  There's a common theme with `Scanner.next()` being here twice when it shouldn't be.